# Rails generate model syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to generate a model from the command line. Here is my command:

> rails generate model User first_name:string last_name:string email_address:string age:integer

And it keeps giving me this error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

User first_name:str last_name:**str** email_address:str age:int

(irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

name:str email_address:str age:**integer**
```

I'm lost. I learned this yesterday and the syntax is exactly the same as before when it worked fine.

Thanks

Edit: StackOverflow wouldnt let me post this unless I formatted that error as code FYI

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should put this command in your system console, not Rails console.

Comment: could you give more detail? I got the error in the frist time,while I run again it ok,what's the problem? I don't know why ,same console,same words

Comment: @Albert.Qing you probably tried to run this command inside of `irb`, interactive ruby console. You should run this in system shell.